# Need to match exact sentences on wsdl - grep/awk/sed

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I am sorry I wil try to explain it better:

I have to do an script which do the following -> Do a curl or a wget of an wsdl and find the following sentences:

`<schema targetNamespace="http://net.jboss.org/jmx" xmlns="asdasd2001/XMLSchema">
    <import namespace=".xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />

    <simpleType name="ObjectNameType">
    <simpleContent>
    <extension base="xsd:string" /> 
    </simpleContent>
    </simpleType>
    </schema>`

And if the sentences are present on the wsdl return me a boolean value - So I was thinking to use grep however, it is not working as I expect because it will check if any of the sentences are on the wsdl. Example

```
   `PcspI01Service%3Fwsdl | grep -F -f ex.bko
    **<import namespace="org/soap/encoding/" /> 
    </schema>
   <import namespace="org/soap/encoding/" /> 
  </schema>**
  <schema targetNamespace="rg/2001/XMLSchema">
  <import namespace="soap/encoding/" /> 
   <simpleType name="ObjectNameType"> 
   <simpleContent>
   <extension base="xsd:string" /> 
   </simpleContent>
     </simpleType>
     </schema>`
```

In this example it shows me that the lines

```
 `<import namespace="org/soap/encoding/" /> 
    </schema>`
```

Are present on the file but that doesn't help me, I need to match all the lines and on the order that they are

Is it more clear now?

Thanks in advance to all!

Comment: This looks like a very indirect and fragile thing to do. Are you sure you don't instead want to e.g. find all files that contain a simpleType named "ObjectNameType" with an extension base "xsd:string"?

Comment: and how you suggest to do it? The thing is that I need to be sure that the order is respected in order to know that it belongs with that part. I am doing a health check script that get the wsdl of a webservice and if I find that sentences I know that the WebService will fail.

Comment: I would suggest matching using XML tools like xmlstarlet or xmllint that understand XML. You don't explain why those lines means there's a bug though, so I can't be more specific.

Comment: I try to clarify it, please let me know if it is more clear now

Comment: Bad: "I need to find this line followed by this line followed by this line in XML files." Good: "I need to find XML files where the simpleType node named "ObjectNameType" has no "restriction" element, because that's a bug."

Comment: I need to do this wish bash, that is the reason why I am not using any xml tool

Answer (score 0):

Are you just saying you want to find a multi-line string in a file? That'd be (using GNU awk for multi-char RS):

```
awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= -v regexp="line1
line2
line3" '$0 ~ regexp' file
```

You didn't post any expected output so the above will just print the whole file if it contains

```
line1
line2
line3
```

If you need a string match rather than a regexp match, use `index()` instead of `~`.

If you don't have gawk, either pick some control char you KNOW can't be in your input file to use as the RS or build up a record string one line at a time using concatenation and then test it in the END section.

If that's not what you're trying to do, edit your question to clarify and add some brief representative input and expected output.